# Form is submitted on page load blank and pa

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form on my web site at http://www.team2457.us/contact_us/sponsorship.php. The first time I filled the form out it worked fine and the php script did what I wanted. But now every time I load the page it displays a popup saying the form was completed successful even though the form has not even loaded yet, and i have not even clicked on the summit button. So I want to know 1) why is it acting like i hit the summit button? 2) why is the form passing the validation im using?

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="http://www.team2457.us" >
        <title>Team 2457 The Law</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/navstyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/style.css">
        <style>
            label {
                display:block;
                margin-top:20px;
                letter-spacing:2px;
            }
            form {
                margin:0 auto;
                width:459px;
            }
            input, textarea {
                width:439px;
                height:27px;
                background:#efefef;
                border:1px solid #dedede;
                padding:10px;
                margin-top:3px;
                font-size:0.9em;
                color:#3a3a3a;
                border-radius:5px;
                -moz-border-radius:5px;
                -webkit-border-radius:5px;
            }
            textarea {
                height:213px;
                background:#efefef;
            }
            input:focus, textarea:focus {
                border:1px solid #97d6eb;
            }
            #submit {
                width:127px;
                height:38px;
                background: #efefef;
                border:none;
                margin-top:20px;
                cursor:pointer;
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header id="banner">
                <img src="imgs/banner.png" align="center" alt="banner"/>
            </header>
            <nav>
                <?php include '../nav.php'; ?>
            </nav>

            <section id="content">
                <?php
                    $name = $_POST['name'];
                    $email = $_POST['email'];
                    $message = $_POST['message'];
                    $from = 'From: potential sponsor'; 
                    $to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; 
                    $subject = 'Sponsor';

                    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";


                    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                        echo '<script>alert("The form was completed succesfuly.");</script>';
                        } 
                    else { 
                        echo '<script>alert("Something whent wrong, try again.");<script>'; 
                        }
                ?>

                <form method="post" action="/contact_us/sponsorship.php">

                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here" value="">

                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here" value="">

                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here" value=""></textarea>

                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

                </form>
            </section>

            <footer>

            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What validation are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mail function is being called every time the page loads. You should consider placing the PHP logic that handles the $_POST variables and mail function inside of an if(isset()) function as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST["name"])){
    //Code to handle input validation and email sending goes here
}
```

Comment: Im doing this for my high school robotics web site. So I'm just learning.

Comment: Sounds like fun! Everybody's just learning something. I would, however, strongly recommend that you apply some kind of validation to the $_POST variables so that your script won't attempt to send an email if an input is left blank or is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, would i use isset() for each form field?

Comment: I'll add another answer to this question to show you something I might do.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured the validation out.